# Couldn't able to get successful gradle build

Tags: gradle, jaxb

Hi I am using gradle version `3.0.0.50`. And this is my dependencies.gradle file's jaxb jar

```
  dependencies {
        compile "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.11"
        compile "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.11"
        xjc "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.11"
  }
```

When I am trying to run `gradle clean build`

I getting the follow stacktrace

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':generat
eEERSClasses'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.ex
ecuteActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.ex
ecute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExec
uter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.exec
ute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execut
e(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecu
ter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter
.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execut
e(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter
.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTa
skWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTa
skWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorW
orker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorW
orker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(Defaul
tTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(Defau
ltTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTask
ExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecute
r.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExec
uter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecu
ter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildEx
ecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecute
r.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecute
r.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLa
uncher.java:154)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(Defaul
tBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(Defaul
tBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(Default
GradleLauncher.java:151)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGra
dleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradl
eLauncher.java:99)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradl
eLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(Defaul
tBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(Defaul
tBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradle
Launcher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLaun
cher.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildCon
troller.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(Exe
cuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildA
ctionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProce
ssBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProce
ssBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(Contin
uousBuildActionExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(Contin
uousBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.exe
cute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.exe
cute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.jav
a:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.
execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.
execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRunti
meValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRunti
meValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(
CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(
CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionRep
ortingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionRep
ortingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBoots
trap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.j
ava:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.ja
va:30)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
        at org.tiaa.reco.build.bootstrapper.GradleBootstrapperWorker.executeBuil
d(GradleBootstrapperWorker.java:128)
        at org.tiaa.reco.build.bootstrapper.GradleBootstrapper.main(GradleBootst
rapper.groovy:46)
Caused by: : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/api/ErrorListener
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:116)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.BasicAntBuilder.nodeCompleted(Bas
icAntBuilder.java:78)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.BasicAntBuilder.doInvokeMethod(Ba
sicAntBuilder.java:93)
        at org.tiaa.reco.build.types.Xjc.generateSources(Xjc.groovy:119)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskF
actory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:227)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskF
actory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskF
actory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(Abstra
ctTask.java:585)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(Abstra
ctTask.java:568)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.ex
ecuteAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.ex
ecuteActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/api/ErrorListener
        at com.sun.istack.tools.ParallelWorldClassLoader.findClass(ParallelWorld
ClassLoader.java:158)
        at com.sun.istack.tools.ParallelWorldClassLoader.findClass(ParallelWorld
ClassLoader.java:158)
        at com.sun.istack.tools.ProtectedTask.execute(ProtectedTask.java:97)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        ... 72 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.api.ErrorListener
        at com.sun.istack.tools.ParallelWorldClassLoader.findClass(ParallelWorld
ClassLoader.java:125)
        ... 77 more
```

Any idea, I tried solutions give [here](https://github.com/jacobono/gradle-jaxb-plugin/issues/15)

But no use. The issue is mainly due to this exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/api/ErrorListener
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
replace compile with xjc...it should work

 dependencies {
        xjc"javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.11"
        xjc "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.11"
        xjc "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.11"
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my existing issue, but further i getting `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0` - which is due to some java version mismatch I guess. Again google solution are not working for this issue.

Comment: well, this comes from classes compiled by never version of java compiler than your runtime